# How do I make my navigation bar link to an external page?

Tags: links

My website is wordswithfriends.net

At the moment all of the top navigation menus link to an internal page.  I want "Contact Us" to link to an external page ask.wordswithfriends.net

How do I do this in the administration panel?  At the moment all I see are options for editing the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your theme and WP version (you're using 2.9.1 - you should consider upgrading).

You can:

- upgrade to V3+ to use the menu editor
  that's built in (recommended) more
  info:
  http://templatic.com/news/wordpress-3-0-menu-management
- hard code your theme template with
  the link added to the end in the HTML
- modify the theme call to
  wp_list_pages() function excluding
  your contact page link (see:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages)